# Runtime error on Integer.parseInt(); i am trying to compare the content in the file and the new value obtained from the method

Tags: exception, numbers, format

/*the below code is i am trying for the notification of new mail i am trying to fetch the prestored value into the file and compare it to the new value from the method

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws MessagingException{
    try {
        Notification n= new Notification();
        int a =n.Notification();
        BufferedReader br = null;

 //read from the earlier file value of the total messages 
            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Notification.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

 int b = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
 if (a>b){
 System.out.println("you have "+(a-b)+" new Messsages");
 }else{
 System.out.println("NO New message");
 }
 //write the new value of the total messages to the file

        Writer output = null;
        File file = new File("Notification.txt");
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        output.write(String.valueOf(a));

        output.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Notification.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        }
```

Comment: sCurrentLine will always be null after the loop ends. Its the condition specified for while loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you are reading from only contains a number that you require, maybe this is what you have to do:

```
       if ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            int b = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
            // do other stuff
       }
       else
       {
            // file empty
       }
```